# Do invisible (display:none) cells count toward colspan

Tags: html, html-table, invisible

Just wondering.  Also, is this applied equally across browsers?

e.g.:

```
<table><tr>
  <td>asdf</td>
  <td style="display:none;">asdf</td>
  <td>asdf</td>
</tr></table>
```

does colspan == 2 or 3?

Comment: You need to explain your question a bit more clearly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `colspan=2`

```css
td[colspan] {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>TL</td>
    <td style="display:none;">HIDDEN</td>
    <td>TC</td>
    <td>TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ML</td>
    <td>MC</td>
    <td>MR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">BL + BC</td>
    <td>BR</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see it with this example expanded

Comment: Thanks Rafal.  Now, do you know if this varies across browsers?

Comment: Also, I was able to make this example - http://jsbin.com/ofuxa4 - that more clearly shows that that it is 2.  You'll see that if you set the colspan to '3' in the last row, that there is a little extra space added to the table... indicating that the table only reports a colspan of 2. Thanks for your help.